# Simplicial maps with chain homotopy induce the same homomorphism on homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following is problem 25 in section 8.6 in Armstrong's topology:

Suppose $s,t \colon \left|  K \right| \to \left| L \right|$ are simplicial, and assume we have a homomorphism $d_q \colon C_q(K) \to C_{q+1}(L)$ for each $q$, such that
$$d_{q-1} \partial  + \partial d_q = t-s \colon C_q(K) \to C_q(L).$$
Show that $s$ and $t$ induce the same homomorphism of homology groups.

Ideas so far: I think it would suffice to show that $t-s$ sends q-cycles of K to q-cycles of L and boundary cycles to boundary cycles. Now for a q-cycle z of K, we have $\partial z = 0$ so $\partial d_q(z) = (t-s)(z)$, however, I'm not sure what to make of that. Furthermore, if $t$ and $s$ are not injective on vertices, so they map some q-simplex $A$ to something of lower dimension, should one interpret $(t-s)(A) = 0$?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, indeed it is a coboundary giving the result immediately, I believe. Thank you. As to the t and s mapping to a simplex of lower dimension, I was just unsure since simplicial maps can map simplexes to simplexes of lower dimension, but I presume since it must map q-chains to q-chains, this is not possible here. As for the homotopy notation, here d is just a homomorphism; I don't believe d is used for homotopies, luckily.

Comment: @kaishin2 The collection of the $d_q$ is a **chain homotopy between $s$ and $t$**.